Brother or cousin or both?
My DNA matches with an adopted brother 45-51% DNA and 3504cm across 50 segments. My ‘brother’ has my aunts name on his birth certificate. We have the same father but working out if we have the same mother.
Could it be his mother is my aunt and my mother is my aunts sister?
So different mothers who were sisters?
We tested on Ancestry.
My mother and aunt are not identical twins. They are sisters, 7 years apart, one looks like the mother, the other like the father.

The Shared cM tool suggests that the only relationship expected between two people who share 3,504 cM is parent-child.
https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/3504
However, be aware of a note at that link:

Important: if you have cM amounts from 23andMe, these will count fully
identical areas twice. This can mean sibling relationships show as
parent/child in this tool.

